# Property 'whileInView' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I have a motion component with the framer-motion property `useInView` in a .tsx file but I'm getting an error:

> Property 'whileInView' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> SVGMotionProps & RefAttributes'

Here's a stripped down version of my component:

```
const LogoIcon = () => {
  //Animation Variants
  const logoAnimation = {
    initial: {
      pathLength: -1,
    },
    animate: {
      pathLength: 1,
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Svg viewBox="0 0 140 158">
        <motion.path
          variants={logoAnimation}
          initial="initial"
          whileInView="animate"
          vectorEffect="non-scaling-stroke"
          d="..."
        />
      </Svg>
    </div>
  );
};

const Svg = styled.svg`
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.gray["700"]};
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-width: 1;
  }
`;

export default LogoIcon;
```

I've used `whileInView` in .js files before and never had this error.

I may be wrong but I get the feeling I need to set proptypes for `useInView`, though I'm not sure how to set them for this property.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It maybe related to this in the [docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/scroll-animations/#scroll-triggered-animations) - *There's currently a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=963246) where IntersectionObserver doesn't work correctly with SVG elements.*

Comment: I read that too, as a test I set up a motion.div with the same property and variants but still get the same error. So I don't think it's related to the bug in Chrome.